# Unable to restart Apache2 in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-11.04

I migrated an old site to a new one and I am trying to rename the old site to legacy.domainname.com

Here is what I have done:
In Linode DNS Manager, I made the necessary DNS updates and the new site is up

For the legacy site
I changed every instance of www.domainname.com to legacy.domainname.com
I made these changes in

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled     and
    /etc/apache2/sites-available

Now I am trying to restart apache2 and it is giving one error after the other, all the errors are like this

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 235 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 30 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/legacy.domainname.com.conf/assets/images/3310sm.jpg: Expected </xapMM:DocumentID>adobe:docid:photoshop:37b23e53-24f1-11dc-83c5-ba417a2e0e5f</xapMM:DocumentID> but saw </rdf:Description>
```

or this

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 235 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 30 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/legacy.txsystems.com.conf/TestFolder/form.phtml_not_needed: Expected </h1><?php> but saw </div>
```

if I remove the referenced file, it will jump to a next thing, now these are files that have worked for 10 years, nothing changed. All I want is to change the domain to legacy
Please can you help point towards a possible troubleshooting step

All I want to run is sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by

Restoring the server from last good backup so I remove my changes
Then I edit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.domainname.com.conf and change
ServerName from www.domainname.com to legacy.domainname.com

Restart apache (/etc/init.d/apache2 restart)

And that is it

Thanks